# Every string between given strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring, match

I need an array of strings which are between two strings but when i use str.match the result is not what I expect:

```
var text = "first second1 third\nfirst second2 third\nfirst second3 third";
var middles = text.match(/first (.*?) third/g);
console.log(middles);  //this should be ["second1", "second2", "second3"]
```

Result:

```
["first second1 third", "first second2 third", "first second3 third"]
```

Is there something I can try to get only the middle strings for each occurrence?

Comment: This would be so much easier if Javascript supported lookbehind. Then you could just do `/(?<=first ).*?(?= third)/g`

Comment: /(?=first )(.*)( ?=third)/g this works but still includes first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec
>   method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>   When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by
>   the regular expression's lastIndex property (test() will also advance
>   the lastIndex property).

Applying this to your case:

```
var text = "first second1 third\nfirst second2 third\nfirst second3 third";
var middles = [], md, regex = /first (.*?) third/g;

while( md = regex.exec(text) ) { middles.push(md[1]); }

middles // ["second1", "second2", "second3"]
```